# return item with jsonb list satisfying all requirements to another jsonb list

Tags: postgresql

I need to find a way to match lets say two lists with strings:

`["stone", "cold", "toast", "exposion"]` // value in column

and `["cold", "explosion", "stone"]` // values to look for

if `["stone", "cold", "toast", "exposion"]` contains EVERY value inside of the input `["cold", "explosion", "stone"]`
which it does in this example, then it passes!

The input can be a list of any number of string values, and it's handled within a python code as $1, the list will have similiar structure found inside of the code below

code example found in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/susZ1iBDiBbZvEJRUKT54i/6

Comment: the first array is a value in a column. the second one? another value of the same column? a second column of the same table? a different table? simply a constant value? Please describe your setting and your expected output more detailled

Comment: The second value is something i'll input using $ sign, so it can be anything

// edited to make it a little more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3699f577ec860a5b64d53f9124adac2b)

Just use the `<@` comparator.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE '["f", "l", "a", "c"]' <@ col
```

[Postgres JSON documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)